# How do I force reconnecting to my database in php?

Tags: php

I wanted my web system to automatically reconnect to the database if it reaches to maximum user connection. Or is there anyway i could reload the page automatically till it is connected to the database

```
$conn =  new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PSWD,DB_NAME);

if($conn->connect_error)
die("Failed to connect database ".$conn->connect_error );
```

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can setting the retry variable(`$retry`) as a flag to mark the DB connection status with default value you want. While connect DB , if it's ok then update retry flag = 0(`$retry=0`) , else reduce the retry one unit (`$retry--`). Also you don't `die` process when have error exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the connection in a function and call it many times you want to retry the connection:

```
function connectDB(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PSWD,DB_NAME)
{
    return $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PSWD,DB_NAME);
}


if(connectDB()->connect_error)
{
    sleep(1);
    if(connectDB()->connect_error)
    {
        die("Failed to connect database ".$conn->connect_error );
    }
}
```

With `sleep(1)` you delay the script to retry the connection after 1 second.

Anyway, you should find the cause of the connection error and solve it; this solution may help you in the case the server is sometimes slow to respond.